# Bootstrap modal dialog return message in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I need some help on return success or error message in bootstrap modal dialog from Partial View in mvc.

When click the link in _LayoutAdmin view, partial view Impersonation.cshtml will load into modal dialog.

After input and click submit button, the popup box will close and post in controller. How to show the error message in modal dialog if user input data is not existed?

Any guidance is highly appreciate!

Screenshot:

[image]

_LayoutAdmin.cshtml:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Impersonation", "UserRoles")" class="modal-link">
  Impersonation &nbsp;
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>

<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
</div>

<script>

 $(function () {

                $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
                    $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
                });
                // Attach listener to .modal-close-btn's so that when the button is pressed the modal dialog disappears
                $('body').on('click', '.modal-close-btn', function () {
                    $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
                });
                //clear modal cache, so that new content can be loaded
                $('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
                });
                $('#CancelModal').on('click', function () {
                    return false;
                });
        });

    </script>
```

(Partial View) Impersonation.csthml:

```
@model FAB_Portal.Models.FAB_View
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("a#impersonate").click(function () {
            var username = $('#UserName').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("Impersonation", "UserRoles")",
                data: { UserName: username },
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        $('#modal-dialog').modal('hide');

                    } else {
                        $('#modal-body').html(result);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;Impersonation</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                @Html.Label("Impersonate", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                @Html.TextBox("UserName", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                <text class="text-danger">@ViewBag.Error</text>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Impersonation", "UserRoles", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok" id="impersonate" >Submit</a>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

UserRoles.Controller:

```
public ActionResult Impersonation()
{
    return PartialView("Impersonation");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Impersonation(FAB_View model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        UserRoleHelper userrolehelper = new UserRoleHelper();
        bool validuser = userrolehelper.CheckValidUser(model.UserName);
        if (validuser == false)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Don't have such user!";
            return PartialView("Impersonation");
        }
        userrolehelper.StartImpersonate(model.UserName);
    }        
    return PartialView("Impersonation");
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to display the `"Don't have such user!"` message?

Comment: exactly, or if username submit success, it will show 'successfully' submited. It's ok, i can add another viewbag for it later, now i just not sure how to pass the message back to the modal dialog.

Comment: Just add `<div>@ViewBag.Error</div>` in your partial view. But there seems no need to return a view - you could just return a value indicating success or failure, and then if failure, display a message

Comment: i have added the viewbag error in partial view..but when i click submit, the modal dialog will straight close..i don't want it close unless it is successfully submited. I'm not sure how to implement it using modal dialog.

Comment: But then how would you display the `"successfully submited"` message? As I noted, it would be better to return json indicating success or otherwise (along with an error message)

Comment: yes...i think only show error message is enough then. Showing successful message is too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix it myself by using below:

[image]

LayoutAdmin view:

```
<script>
 $(function () {

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $("#impersonate").on("click", function (e) {

            // hide dropdown if any
            $(e.target).closest('.btn-group').children('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');

            $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
                    /*backdrop: 'static',*/
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');
                bindForm(this);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

    function bindForm(dialog) {

        $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,

                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        //Refresh
                        location.reload();
                    } else {
                        $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                        bindForm();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }

</script>
```

Impersonation.cshtml:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Impersonation(FAB_View model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                UserRoleHelper userrolehelper = new UserRoleHelper();
                var loggedonuser = userrolehelper.GetLoggedOnUser();
                var currentuser = userrolehelper.GetCurrentUser();

                bool validuser = userrolehelper.CheckValidUser(model.UserName);

                if (validuser == false)
                {
                    ViewBag.Error = "* Don't have such user!";
                    return PartialView("Impersonation", model);
                    //return Json(new { success = false });
                }
                else
                {
                    //userrolehelper.StartImpersonate(model.UserName);
                    return Json(new { success = true });
                }               
            }

            return PartialView("Impersonation", model);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Modify (Partial View) Impersonation.csthml:

```
  @model FAB_Portal.Models.FAB_View
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Impersonation", "UserRoles", FormMethod.Post,new { @id="form" }))
                { 

    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;Impersonation</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    @Html.Label("Impersonate", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    @Html.TextBox("UserName", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    <text class="text-danger">@ViewBag.Error</text>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok" id="impersonate" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
    <script type="text/javascript">

            $("a#impersonate").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("Impersonation", "UserRoles")",
                    data:   $('#form').serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result == "success") {
                            $('#dialogDiv').modal('hide');

                        } else {
                            $('#dialogContent').html(result);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
```

UserRoles.Controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Impersonation(FAB_View model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        UserRoleHelper userrolehelper = new UserRoleHelper();
        bool validuser = userrolehelper.CheckValidUser(model.UserName);
        if (validuser == false)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Don't have such user!";
            return Content("error");
        }
        userrolehelper.StartImpersonate(model.UserName);
    }        
    return Content("success");
}
```

Try this and don't forget to Hit like if it works.
Let me know if it's not working going to provide another way or modify this one.

Comment: can you please insert alert(result); in success function and reply with the response you are getting

Comment: or provide me your project to fix it.